# Android JSON request: App crashes caused by "utf8"?

Tags: php, android, json, request

**Edit**
I solve my problem: Just replaced `mysql_query('set names utf8');` with `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$con);` ($con is my "mysql_connect")

---

Since I added in my PHP-File

```
mysql_query('set names utf8');
```

my Andorid App crashes. Before that, all works fine but I got an "null"-problem with "öäü" in my JSON request so I need to add *'set names utf8'* in my php java request

Android Error log:

```
 Attempt to invoke virtual method 'org.json.JSONObject org.json.JSONArray.getJSONObject(int)' on a null object reference
```

Here my void in my Actitity Class:

```
public void setTextToTextViewText(JSONArray jsonArray) {

    String s = "";
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        s = json.getString("Eventbeschr") + "\n" + "\n" +
                "Spiel: " + json.getInt("Spiel") + "\n" +
                "Beginn: " + json.getString("EventDatum") + "\n" +
                "Max. Teilnehmer: " + json.getInt("maxTeilnehmer") + "\n" +
                "\n";
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        this.textView_eventTitel.setText(R.string.eventinfo_getting_text_error_body);
    }
    this.textView_eventInfo.setText(s);

}

private class GetLastEventTask extends AsyncTask<ApiConnector, Long, JSONArray> {

    @Override
    protected JSONArray doInBackground(ApiConnector... params) {

        return params[0].GetLatestEvent();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {

        setTextToTextViewHead(jsonArray);
    }


}
```

In my onCreate, I call:

```
new GetLastEventTask().execute(new ApiConnector());
```

My ApiConnector.java file

```
public class ApiConnector {
    public JSONArray GetLatestEvent()
    {
        String url = "MY URL TO PHP FILE";


        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

        try
        {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  // Default HttpClient
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

            httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();



        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Convert HttpEntity into JSON Array
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;

        if (httpEntity != null) {
            try {
                String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                Log.e("Entity Response  : ", entityResponse);

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return jsonArray;
    }
}
```

Maby its helpful, but here is also the main piece of my PHP-File:

```
    mysql_select_db("DB NAME", $con);

$result=mysql_query('set names utf8');

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM event ORDER BY EventID desc limit 1");

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;

}
print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Seems jsonArray is null

Comment: @Rohit5k2 In my browser I see the output, so this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that when I assemble arrays and then json_encode them that I have to utf8_encode the values in the array to keep it from throwing the occasional error.

Try:

```
$output[] = utf8_encode($row);
```

Edit:

Sorry for not catching that $row was an array on first read.  For that you will have to build your dataset out a little more piecemeal where you increment a key through the while and add each field you want into the array manually (obviously replacing my placeholder field names with your real ones).

```
$key = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[$key]['field1'] = utf8_encode($row['field1']);
    $output[$key]['field2'] = utf8_encode($row['field2']);
    $key++;
}
```

Another alternative could be to us a function like array_map to do the encoding over the already assembled array:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $output[]=$row;
}
$output = array_map("utf8_encode", $output);
```

Comment: I get this error: 'Warning: utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /var/customers/webs/ni161189_1/json-sql/getLatestEvent.php on line 18 [null]'
Line 18 is your code your answer